# Can't build Xamarin.Forms app for UWP in release mode

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

Stackoverflow community!

I can't build release version of app, because it crashes on this line of code.
I try remove assemblies to include...
But this not resolve my issue.

```
List<Assembly> assembliesToInclude = new List<Assembly>();
assembliesToInclude.Add(typeof(CarouselViewRenderer).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
assembliesToInclude.Add(typeof(UWPShadowsRenderer).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e, assembliesToInclude);
```

Help me please.

Thank you!
Best wishes!

Comment: for me it crashed because I missed one line. Make sure you add all dependencies here

Comment: In debug mode it working.

Comment: debug mode is not using .net native, but you can activate .net native in UWP project options for debug

Comment: How I can do that?

Comment: Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid.

Comment: I have this exception.

Comment: activate this option: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNCr8.png

Comment: This option enabled in release mode.

Comment: Enabled by default.

Comment: you should do it for debug and run it in debug mode

Comment: How I can publish it?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean

Comment: I want build Release version of my Xamarin.Forms UWP app and publish it to the Microsoft Store. But I have bulding problem.

Comment: Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid.

Comment: Packages generated in Debug mode impossible to send.

Comment: you should debug your code with .net native enabled to see the cause of your crash. if you fixed that create the release version

Comment: If I use .NET Native compilation I catch exception 'Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid.'. On Xamarin.Forms.Init() line.

Comment: I don't know how resolve this...

Comment: ok, so mismatch of cpu architecture. make sure you compile all projects with same architecture (x86, x64, ARM64)

Comment: I try to compile my library for x86. But this is not resolve my issue.

Comment: Library x86 and UWP project x86 but problem not resolved.

Comment: magicandre1981 please help

Comment: I have no idea. Try to compile and run x64

Comment: in [config manager make sure that platforms match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/visualstudio/ide/how-to-configure-projects-to-target-platforms?view=vs-2019). also share the csproj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve this problem.
In my project was a package that caused this problem.
When I delete package project became working.

Comment: which package was the cause?